# Is it possible to search files of particular extension in the entire device?

Tags: iphone, nsfilemanager, nsfilehandle, nsfilewrapper

In my application, i am trying to find all files of particular extension (like .pdf, .txt, etc) that are stored in the device (either downloaded or transferred from system) and want to list them in table View. Is it possible to do so and if it is then can i associate file of specific extension to get it open in supporting application (any third party plug-ins).I went through numerous documentation but couldn't find the solution. Also how can i index files of these extension for fast search.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: I have posted this question a week ago since then no reply or answer. i can guess i have asked a weird question. Basically what i want to do is to search is there any pdf file early downloaded into the device and if there is any i'll put it into the dictionary with its location as key and its title as value.

Comment: Is this for jailbroken devices? Otherwise you can't search *all* files.

Answer (score 0):

No, it's not possible. You app can't access files of other apps directly.